# Why doesn't this regex pattern match this text? (Simple regex just includes escaped text with wildcard in the middle)

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, assertions, nunit-2.5

Apologies if this is a duplicate; I promise I did search.

I'm working on a C# integration testing project using NUnit in Visual Studio 2010 Professional, running the tests with Resharper v6.1. (Resharper 6.1 dictates that I use NUnit 2.5.10; I've always had trouble trying to override that.)

Part of my testing is to assert that the proper exceptions are thrown, including the exception messages. However, sometimes the exception message includes a guid or other information that I don't expect to be the exact same every time. To get around this, I want to match the exception message using a basic regex pattern where I include the exception message and simply use a wildcard where in certain spots to say "this part can match anything" I've tried to do this in the scenario below, but every time I get an error that there is no match. Summary of the code:

```
[Test]
public void ExceptionPatternTest()
{
var patternA = Regex.Escape(@"SQL Code: 2601 Message: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ResourceCategory' with unique index 'IDX_ResourceTypeResourceCategoryName'.");
var patternB = ".*";  //wildcard
var patternC = Regex.Escape(@"\r\nThe statement has been terminated.");    
var pattern = patternA + patternB + patternC;

var thrownException = Assert.Throws(Is.TypeOf(_testException.GetType()),
               () => Throw()); //Call method and assert that exception is thrown.

Assert.That(Regex.IsMatch(thrownException.Message, pattern));
}

private void Throw()
{
    throw _testException;
}

readonly Exception _testException = new Exception("SQL Code: 2601 Message: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ResourceCategory' with unique index 'IDX_ResourceTypeResourceCategoryName'. The duplicate key value is (9fec90c1-12b4-42c3-adc0-a0d600b9a8e8, 1, Item Cat 1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated.");
```

I've also tried variations on parts of this. Including a manual escaping of characters for the pattern:

```
var pattern = @"SQL\ Code:\ 2601\ Message:\ Cannot\ insert\ duplicate\ key\ row\ in\ object\ 'dbo\.ResourceCategory'\ with\ unique\ index\ 'IDX_ResourceTypeResourceCategoryName'\..*\\r\\nThe\ statement\ has\ been\ terminated\.";
```

And I've tried StringAssert too, in case there was a difference:

```
StringAssert.IsMatch(pattern, thrownException.Message);
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Also, apologies if I'm just missing something really dumb. I've only worked with regex sparingly, so that is certainly possible.

Comment: Do you really need to verify the _entire_ error message (and thus break your tests on the slightest change)? I'd say that `Message.StartsWith("SQL Code: 2601 Message: Cannot insert duplicate key row");` would be ample identification.

Comment: Don't **abuse** regexps this way. I wouldn't be surprised if the `\r\n` is causing the problems, actually. Try replacing parts of your pattern (like first half, second half) with `.*` to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you for the suggestion; it makes sense. However I'm not sure how to integrate it with my current project structure. I have a method that runs all of my exception tests, so I don't have to duplicate the assert throws and match code you see above over and over. I either match the exception message exactly, or I have the option to match based on a pattern. That makes it hard to use something as specific as Message.StartsWith for the assertion. I know this might sound like an unusual structure, but it is integration testing, not unit testing, if that helps explain.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Fair enough. I know this isn't the normal usage for regex; it's certainly not input validation. I did learn that the .* wildcard will not match the linebreak characters, which is why they're including in patternC, but I was able to match a regex pattern with them in a similar message. Do you have another suggestion for how I can accomplish my task? I really am all ears. I put some more explanation in my comment to HenkHolterman, if it's helpful.

Comment: The StartsWith was just te basic idea. You can write a simple Regex to match just the start of a message. But it all depends on the requirements, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Regex.Escape(@"\r\n")` will produce `\\r\\n`, which is not what you want. I would suggest moving the newline to the unescaped string instead:

```
var patternB = @".*\r\n";
var patternC = Regex.Escape(@"The statement has been terminated.");
```

Comment: That did it! Fantastic and thank you very much! I'm glad it turned out to be something simple.

Comment: I recognized this because I ran into the same issue myself a few years ago. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a complicated regex when you can just use `string.StartsWith` and `string.EndsWith` to check the prefix and suffix? Less code, easier to read, and no messing about trying to work out why a seemingly simple thing doesn't work right.

Comment: That is definitely a valid question. I tried to explain in my comment to HenkHolterman above. In summary, I'm using a assert throws method of my own throughout my project and I can't use such specific assertions; I pass in a regex pattern instead. But you're making me reconsider; maybe I can pass in a more specific form of assertion. I will think on it more. Thanks for your feedback.